# Как исправить ошибку pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Здраствуйте.
Делаю кликер для игры на нейронной сети yolo.
Обучил нейронку и не могу ее использовать в программе.
Вот код:

```
import torch


model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='./model/best-m.pt', force_reload=True)
```

Выбивает ошибку:
Exception: 'Detect' object has no attribute 'grid'. Cache may be out of date, try `force_reload=True` or see https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/36 for help.

Answer (score 0):

а если так использовать:
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', pretrained=True)
(в кэш загружается предобученная модель)